# Correct syntax to execute "array" variable as a function?

Tags: php

I have the following array:

```
$bla = array (
   'function1', 'function2'
);
```

Assume the following function exists:

```
function1
```

How would I call it using the variable? This doesn't work:

```
$bla[0]();
```

What is the correct syntax?

*Update*

Also, what is the correct way to call it if the function has parameters?

Comment: It should be possible as of PHP 5.4

Comment: Your example should just work: http://3v4l.org/ZBeKc

Comment: possible duplicate of [Array of reference to function in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25760793/array-of-reference-to-function-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`call_user_func`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) function:

```
call_user_func($bla[0]);
```

Comment: How would I then call it with parameters?

Comment: @coderama `call_user_func_array()`. But still, as of PHP 5.4 you can use the syntax you were trying

Comment: You can either use `call_user_func($bla[0], 'one', 'two')` or `call_user_func_array($bla[0], array('one', 'two'))`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [`call_user_func`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php).

And if you want to add some parameters, use : [`call_user_func_array`](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.call-user-func-array.php)